# SelfSTS (to test ADFS in local environment) is retired. Is there a replacement for it?

Tags: asp.net, adfs

I am new in ADFS and want to implement it to integrate our user authentication with an external authentication server. First I want to do that in the development environment to be able to test it.

I've done a bit research and found some documents that used [SelfSTS](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SelfSTS). It seems that this application is retired now.

Is there any other similar Security Token Service that I could use for testing purposes?

Comment: Can you explain how ADFS is being used with your application? Capturing some of the interchange and having it replayed with minor modification using a small ASP.NET app might be one option. We have a similar app for simulating SAML authentication when a product like ADFS isn't available.

Comment: We have our Authentication Mechanism in our web application for all of our clients. One of our clients wants our application use ADFS to authenticate the users. They will provide us the Authentication server and we suppose to connect to that to authenticate the users. But because I'm not sure if they have configured the server properly I prefer to  test it locally first. We did use SAML for another client to implement the SSO but this client wants us to use ADFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a RP and you want to test authenticating with this RP against ADFS?

Why don't you just install ADFS locally and test your RP to ADFS via WIF?

Using something like SelfSTS doesn't really help.

You could use it to test the WIF integration but there's no guarantee that changing to ADFS will work.

If you can't install ADFS, use [IdentityServer](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2). That's an open source STS that you can install locally and test the WIF integration.

Comment: Because I am new in ADFS first I want to test it locally to see if I am doing the right thing. Also I am not sure if our client(RP) has configured their server correctly. I am going to try the integration with their server now and if I don't succeed I will try the IdentityServer that you suggested.